# Why are javadocs evil and what's a better alternative?

Tags: java, javadoc

I recently went for an interview and was requested to submit an example of my production code.

Submitted the code complete with javadocs, but was questioned by the interviewer about my choice of it.

I find javadocs quite useful for understanding code by others and it's really not that much of a legibility issue if I'm using an IDE. Can someone enlighten me on why it may not be recommended and what would be a better alternative in said situation?

Comment: What was the interviewer's point of view?

Comment: Not putting java docs and appropriate comments in a large product is *suicidal*.

Comment: javadocs are good. It is more important *what* and *how* you put in there

Comment: Interviewers are allowed to question you on things that aren't wrong...

Comment: The interviewer mentioned that javadocs in general makes code incredibly hard to read. Which I think is a non-issue since I can hide them in IDEs if I want to. I thought it was a way for the interviewer to challenge my thinking and have a good discussion about clean code, turns out she really thought it was evil, and the company apparently uses a third party documentation tool which she did not tell me what it was.

Comment: Sounds like a terrible place to work.  Keep doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

Javadocs are **not** evil, and for Java it's the **best** you can do to properly document your code.

Being questioned does not mean automatically that what you've done is evil. Questions are mostly to test if you're sure in what you do and if you know more about it or you just made a guess.

Comment: I'd go beyond "best" and say that Javadoc is the *only* acceptable format for documenting Java code, period.  It was established as the standard by the creators of the language.  How much more authoritative can you get?